# What Are Some Good Southern Hemisphere 7x50 Binocular Targets?

Tags: amateur-observing, binoculars

I've been interested in astronomy for a while but only recently purchased my first set of binoculars (7x50). I've been learning various constellations as well as spotting some other objects with the help of my planisphere. I live in the suburbs of a big Australian city, but far enough out that the light pollution isn't too bad.

I've already been looking at objects like the Orion Nebula and Pleiades, but hoped some experts might be able to give me a list of objects that would be worth hunting down with my binoculars. Ideally some that would be visible now (it's Summer here), but some for other times of the year would also be fine.

Comment: Found a pile for southern binoculars here: https://books.google.com/books?id=foTRJ8yQcwEC&pg=PA154&lpg=PA154&dq=tarantula+nebula+binoculars&source=bl&ots=ozuWf6ap2o&sig=23A3IfrdJy98rmURKQg-ss1mM6Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlqujKpPDKAhXG4iYKHTVcAmYQ6AEIMzAG#v=onepage&q=tarantula%20nebula%20binoculars&f=false

Comment: related: [Binocular highlights from Tasmania next few weeks?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34026/7982)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone else who might be asking a similiar question, I found a great resource for this. The PDFs found at the URL below contain a good list of binocular, naked-eye and telescope targets for each month of the year in both hemispheres.

http://www.skymaps.com/downloads.html

Answer (score 5):

- Pleiades -  a jewel box (open star cluster)
- Coal Sack - in Crucis, there's a globular cluster I recall there somewhere. Hours of fascination.
- Messier objects
- Jupiter moons
- Saturn's rings and moons,
- Lyra (constellation)
- Large and Small Magellanic Clouds - extra-galactic remnants on the southern pole of the Milky Way

Just for starters. By the time you work through all these, you'll start to gain an appreciation of your own.

Happy Hunting!!!