# Line of satellite like moving objects

Tags: amateur-observing, artificial-satellite, identify-this-object

Earlier this morning when I went outside to get a drink around 04:00 Tasmanian time (GMT +11), I saw a line of moving lights in the night sky. They were all moving at the same speed similar distances from one another in straight line apart from the last two that were more spread out and out of line. There was around 20-25 of them although I couldn't get a final count as I couldn't be certain there more at the start of the line that had gone past my sightline. They all moved and looked like satellites so it's possible it's some sort of strange cluster I don't know about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Line of lights moving in a straight line, with a few following](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32034/line-of-lights-moving-in-a-straight-line-with-a-few-following)

Comment: this is unrelated except for the time zone, but there was a recent question: [Binocular highlights from Tasmania next few weeks?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34026/7982)

Comment: I would like to see that too but in Italy it seemed non possible :(