# How much time do I have left to easily spot the recently brightened Recurrent Nova RS Ophiuchi with binoculars and mild light pollution?

Tags: observational-astronomy, amateur-observing, light-curve, time-domain-astronomy, nova

Excellent answers to [Binocular-friendly star map to find the Recurrent Nova RS Ophiuchi?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/45272/7982) provide some helpful maps for circa  8° FOV binoculars, but due to spatial and potential meteorological challenges I can't get them between me and a clear sky this weekend.

How long do I have to see the [Recurrent Nova RS Ophiuchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS_Ophiuchi) before it fades substantially?

If I miss it this time, how long do I have to wait for it to "recur"?

Comment: what does the "how long" mean ? exposure time ?

Comment: @Ishwaran The body of the question says: "How long do I have... before it fades substantially?" I've changed the title to "How much time do I have left..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RS Ophiuchi is "Currently" Shining at a apparent magnitude of 5.12 (initially 4.6.) . It is fading at a rate of 0.01 and continues this progress for the next 43-47 days. Then it will fade at a rate of 0.02 and reaches its pre-burst luminosity with apparent magnitude of 10 to 12. Usually binoculars (take 8x42) will be able to spot this with magnitude less than 6.7 (with respect to class 3 light pollution at 24 degree Celsius and low air pollution {Rural-scale}). So You have roughly 56 days left to see it clearly, in best case scenario, Sooner you catch it, bigger the quality of the image. Recurrence of RS Ophiuchi's nova averages at 10-15 years (min - 7, max - 33).